# Postgresql get sum of latest records for all distinct ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following table:

```
<id: 1, location: "New York" product_id: 1, amount: 10, date: "2020-06-23T20:04:12">
<id: 2, location: "New York" product_id: 1, amount: 20, date: "2020-06-20T00:00:45">
<id: 3, location: "New York" product_id: 2, amount: 50, date: "2020-06-19T23:26:21">
<id: 4, location: "New York" product_id: 3, amount: 50, date: "2020-06-24T00:00:00">
<id: 5, location: "Ottawa" product_id: 1, amount: 20, date: "2020-06-12T00:00:00">
<id: 6, location: "Ottawa" product_id: 1, amount: 30, date: "2020-06-22T00:00:00">
<id: 7, location: "Ottawa" product_id: 2, amount: 40, date: "2020-06-23T00:00:00">
```

I want to write a raw sql query that sums the total `amount` per location, but it only adds the amount once per product id. So, when there are records with similar `product_id`, the record it chooses, is the record closest to but less than the `max_date` variable. So for example, let's say that `max_date` = "2020-06-24T00:00:00", the response when querying the above table would be:

```
{
   "New York":60, #exludes ids 2, 3
   "Ottawa": 70 #exludes id 4
}
```

Any help would be great. Sorry if this is a noob question, kinda new with postgresql (or sql in general).

Comment: Is there a reason why `id: 3` is repeated?

Comment: @MikeOrganek sorry corrections made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this.

The `keeps` CTE limits the query to records before the cutoff `"date"` and assigns numbers to your rows.

The main query then picks only the ones where `row_number()` was `1`, and calculates the sum by location.

```
with keeps as (
  select location, product_id, amount,
         row_number() over (partition by location, product_id 
                                order by "date" desc) as rn
    from sales
   where "date" < '2020-06-24'
)
select location, sum(amount) as amount
  from keeps
 where rn = 1
 group by location;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. This example really helped me understand window functions. Clarifies the line from the docs "...the rows retain their separate identities."